# .then function problems uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'then' of undefined;

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Hi i have problems when i compiling the aplication with android 6.0 i only make this code an use cordova-plugin-local-notifications and cordova for build the app, something wrong in the code? thanks

```
  if (window.cordova) {
        window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 2,
            title: 'Good Evening!',
            text: "It's time to take 2",
            every: 2,
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log('Notification 2 triggered');
            navigator.vibrate(1500);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This function 'window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule' probably returned undefined.

Comment: then, what is the best form for make window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule and later other function

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs to indicate it returns a promise, unless you've promisified it. The docs show a callback. You can't randomly decide what something you didn't write returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surround your code with

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  //your code
});
```

don't forget to add the correct plugin to cordova
and if you use angular maybe use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/

EDIT ANSWER from jonathan and [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) : make use of proper callback for schedule function

```
if (window.cordova) {
  window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({ id: 2, title: 'Good Evening!', text: "It's time to take 2", every: 2, }, vibrate); 
} 
function vibrate() { 
  navigator.vibrate(2000); 
}
```

Comment: ok i research for my script, and i can call a callback later

      if (window.cordova) {
            window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 2,
                title: 'Good Evening!',
                text: "It's time to take 2",
                every: 2,
            }), vibrate;
        }
    
    
        function vibrate() {
            navigator.vibrate(2000);
        }

Comment: you can write my own answer please? i cannot post my own answer